# Invoke VmWare PowerCLI from C#

Tags: c#, vmware, powercli

Is there a way to execute the PowerCLI cmdlets from within C#? Basically we have a workflow written using Windows Workflow. At certain stages in the execution of this workflow we need to interact with certain virtual machines and turn them on/off or toggle the persistent mode of the disks etc.

While we can use the .NET toolkit and achieve what we need, it makes sense to explore the possibility of achieving this via PowerCLI cmdlets because pretty much all that we need to do can be very easily done via PowerCLI cmdlets.

Answer (score 2):

PowerCLI is a PowerShell-based wrapper for the [VIX API](http://www.vmware.com/support/developer/vix-api/).

If you want to develop a script in pure PowerShell Syntax because it makes life easier for you, you should launch a PowerShell process and just run the PowerCLI code.

If you want to automate VMware tasks through C#, you should look up the [vSphere API](http://www.vmware.com/support/developer/vc-sdk/). It has bindings for the dot.net framework.

Comment: You can find vSphere API C# code samples here: http://communities.vmware.com/community/vmtn/developer/codecentral/vsphere_ws_c

Comment: Sorry I was referring to code samples that can demonstrate calling VMWare PowerCLI cmdlets from C#

Comment: Write a regular powercli script, and save it as a `.ps1` file. Then spawn a new powershell process with C# and pass the powercli script as an argument.

Comment: Can you please approve the answer if it helped you?